# RDX Cartridge change not recognized

Tags: debian

I have a problem with a RDX-Cartridge System. The device is connected via USB to our debian system. When I insert a new cartridge debian recognizes the cartridge as supposed. I can mount it, access the data, unmount it and eject the cartridge from the drive without any problems.
But if I want to add the same cartridge or a new one later, these cartridges will not be recognized by debian. Only if i repower the cardridge-drive or replug the USB-connection it works fine again.

does anyone has an idea? i added the dmesg output, maybe it can help. I replugged the USB-connection.
Best regards.

```
[349999.796719] usb 3-12: USB disconnect, device number 3
[350004.185889] usb 3-12: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[350004.314655] usb 3-12: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=1102
[350004.314657] usb 3-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[350004.314658] usb 3-12: Product: RDX-USB3
[350004.314659] usb 3-12: Manufacturer: IMATION
[350004.314660] usb 3-12: SerialNumber: 00A13267K020
[350004.315069] usb-storage 3-12:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[350004.315173] scsi9 : usb-storage 3-12:1.0
[350006.637655] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     IMATION  RDX-USB3         4103 PQ: 0 ANSI: 3
[350006.637932] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[350006.638557] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdh] 625134256 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[350006.638766] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
[350006.638769] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[350006.638966] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
[350006.638990] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
[350006.643892]  sdh: sdh1
[350006.644903] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
[350441.583835] sdh: detected capacity change from 320068739072 to 0
[351660.132528] usb 3-12: USB disconnect, device number 6
[351663.684452] usb 3-12: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[351663.813200] usb 3-12: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=1102
[351663.813202] usb 3-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[351663.813203] usb 3-12: Product: RDX-USB3
[351663.813204] usb 3-12: Manufacturer: IMATION
[351663.813204] usb 3-12: SerialNumber: 00A13267K020
[351663.813630] usb-storage 3-12:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[351663.813806] scsi10 : usb-storage 3-12:1.0
[351666.151518] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     IMATION  RDX-USB3         4103 PQ: 0 ANSI: 3
[351666.151756] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[351666.152308] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdh] 625134256 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[351666.152513] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
[351666.152515] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[351666.152744] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
[351666.152760] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
[351666.157799]  sdh: sdh1
[351666.158806] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: The dmesg output you included is for when it worked, you unplugged/replugged, and it worked again.  Can you add the dmesg content from when a cartridge didn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but thats the log when its not working.  I Disconnect the Drive: [350441.583835] sdh: detected capacity change from 320068739072 to 0   after that nothing is working anymore so i have to reconnect the USB drive [351660.132528] usb 3-12: USB disconnect, device number 6

Comment: After put the new cartdrige try partprobe or partx